# if statement that contains a "round" function

Tags: ms-access

Please fix my if-statement, based on my criteria, listed below.  I am getting  the error message “the expression you entered contains invalid syntax. You may have entered a comma without a preceding value or identifier”.

Criteria:
1.  If mth_sply365 value  is greater than “0” and less than “1”, then round to one decimal place.
2.  If mth_sply365 value is not greater than “0” and less than “1”, then round to zero decimals.

```
IIf([u].[mth_sply365] >0 and <1,Round([u].[mth_sply365],1),Round([u].[mth_sply365],0))
```

Thanks in advance, Nathaniel

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think your statement should be as follows :
`IIf([u].[mth_sply365] >0 and [u].[mth_sply365] <1,Round([u].[mth_sply365],1),Round([u].[mth_sply365],0))`.
`[u].[mth_sply365]` should be specified before each condition. Good luck.